# I wanted to add column deletion feature to my chart but it works wrong

Tags: angular, typescript, algorithm, charts

At first, when I delete a column from the left, it does not cause any problems.but then when I delete a column from the right it doesn't delete that column

```
 onDeleteColumnByIndex(selectedColIndex: number) {
  this.element.rows.forEach(row => {
  row.columns = row.columns.filter(o => o.colIndex != selectedColIndex);
  row.columns.forEach((cell, index) => cell.colIndex == index);
});

   this.element.col--;  
// This block of code was written to resize the table. do not pay attention ==>>>>>> 
   this.element.ReCalculateCellSize();
```

}

E.g; 1 2 3. I want to delete the 2nd, when I delete the first 1, it is deleted without any problems, then when I press 3 to delete, 2 is deleted.

Comment: Hi! Welcome.
 row.columns.forEach((cell, index) => cell.colIndex == index); 

This line does not have any sense. Check your logic here.

Comment: umm i don't know, i have a really big logic error somewhere.

Comment: ok guys it's my fault :) I should have written cell.colIndex instead of colIndex in the html part, I think I got distracted